# configure pam with ssh to do 2 factor authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

I am trying to configure ssh with my custom radius server for authentication.

So what i want is, First it should authenticate with current ssh  login (unix login) and then prompt user for second password for radius.

I am setting up /etc/pam.d/sshd as follows

```
auth        required    pam_unix.so debug

**auth       sufficient   /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so  debug conf=/home/pam_radius try_first_pass**
```

But then my first authentication does not happen at all. It immediately goes for radius.

As per pam_radius ..try_first_pass

> ....If there was no previous password, or
>   the previous password
>                    fails authentication, prompt the user with
>                    "Enter RADIUS password: ", and ask for another
>   password.
>                    Try this password, and return success/failure as
>   appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reply to the comments of the other answer, but have you tried setting both `auth` lines to `required` instead of having radius be set as `sufficient`?

Comment: That's a good place to start.  They are both required, after all; just radius is *not* to be considered sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

i think your ssh login fails and then directly goes to the radius authentication. what happens when you enter a radius passwort? when my guess is correct your auth should fail, no matter whether you enter a correct or false password for your radius auth.

to debug this problem a bit more, please post your debug output.

you should disable your radius auth to be sure your ssh auth is working.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. 

What i want is other-way. if pam_unix login is successful then go for radius. (That is 2 factor authentication) (I also tried changing "auth required" to "requisite")

In my case, it does not do first authentication with pam_unix at all. It immediately goes to radius. 

1. If i remove radius from stack. It does do unix authentication .
2. If i remove pam_unix, same behaviour as mentioned. It goes to radius auth 
3. If I keep pam_unix AFTER radius, If radius auth fails, it does unix auth. 

(What i want is other way round. First do unixAuth, if success, do radius auth.)

Comment: "what happens when you enter a radius password" 
- It passes.

"you should disable your radius auth to be sure your ssh auth is working." 

- yes it works.

In curx, problem is, when pam_unix is first, It does not go through pam_unix (or it does but no debug. I have enabled debug. Posting them)

Comment: /var/log/secure

Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_radius_auth: Got user name jigar
Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_radius_auth: Got password <****>
Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_radius_auth: Sending RADIUS request code 1
Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_radius_auth: DEBUG: getservbyname(radius, udp) returned 8089344.
Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_radius_auth: Got RADIUS response code 3
Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_radius_auth: authentication failed

Comment: Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: Accepted password for jigar from 192.168.0.39 port 5604 ssh2
Jan 25 12:26:28 jigarnb sshd[10686]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jigar by (uid=0)

Comment: As of logs, It says "It tried with radius, but failed so used unix" But why ? My unix stack is at the top ? Why it tried with radius first ?

Comment: some more ideas: perhaps it is working in the right order, but the messages are printed in wrong order to the log. change pam_unix parameter from `debug` to `audit`. make your radius auth work alone than enable unix and radius and look at the order of the log messages.

Comment: So i did exactly as you said 
#auth       required    pam_unix.so audit
auth       sufficient    /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so  debug conf=/home/jigar/nvsotp_server/pam_radius try_first_pass

It works

Comment: Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: pam_radius_auth: Got user name jigar
Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: pam_radius_auth: Sending RADIUS request code 1
Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: pam_radius_auth: DEBUG: getservbyname(radius, udp) returned 8261376.
Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: pam_radius_auth: Got RADIUS response code 2

Comment: Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: pam_radius_auth: authentication succeeded
Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: Accepted password for jigar from 192.168.0.39 port 38934 ssh2
Jan 25 16:05:24 jigarnb sshd[23011]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jigar by (uid=0)

Comment: Now changed to enable pam_unix
auth       required    pam_unix.so audit
auth       sufficient    /lib/security/pam_radius_auth.so  debug conf=/home/jigar/nvsotp_server/pam_radius try_first_pass

Comment: It tried to authenticate with radius and failed. and accepted unix credential.

Comment: Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_radius_auth: Got user name jigar
Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_radius_auth: Got password ******
Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_radius_auth: Sending RADIUS request code 1
Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_radius_auth: DEBUG: getservbyname(radius, udp) returned -1217982720.
Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_radius_auth: Got RADIUS response code 3

Comment: Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_radius_auth: authentication failed
Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: Accepted password for jigar from 192.168.0.39 port 40712 ssh2
Jan 25 16:10:00 jigarnb sshd[23339]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jigar by (uid=0)

Comment: Its strange. Why it went to radius for first time ? It should have gone to unix instead. And making it audit didn't help.